# Windows 7 Default Permissions When Saving File

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2003

We have a new Windows 7 machine and when saving a file to a network directory only the person that created that file can see it.  I have figured out that it's a permissions problem.  My question is how can I make files saved to a network folder default to be accessible to everyone?  The folder is on a Server 2003 machine and this problem only occurs when a Windows 7 machine creates a file in that folder.

Answer (score 2):

Files should be inheriting permissions from the parent directory ... try this:

Right click the directory, go to properties, then the `security` tab. Click `advanced`. Add *Everyone* (are you sure you don't want *authenticated users*?). Once you've added *Everyone,* double-click the entry. Set the `apply onto` dropdown to `this folder, subfolders, and files.` Alternatively, set it to `subfolders and files only` so that the permissions on the folder would be the same as before, but anything created in them would have the permissions you assigned to `Everyone`.

Now make sure you have the correct permissions so you don't accidentally give everybody full control.